# log4j doesn't create log files

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I tryed to use `log4j` for my easy project.

All output to console works ok. But output to files with creating log file doesn't work.

**Log4j.xml**

```
    <!-- Appenders -->
    <!-- Loggin into console -->
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p: %c - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="append" value="false" />
        <param name="file" value="demoApplication.log" />
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p (%F:%L:%M)  %c{1}  - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- Root logger -->
    <root>
        <priority value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="file" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>

    <!-- Application Loggers -->
    <logger name="com.softserve.edu">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Here is my project struckture:

[image]

Why does this happen? For me, all should works ok.

**Any suggestions?**

Comment: Try refreshing your project. Also, are you running it through Eclipse?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis of course under eclipse. refreshing doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a relative path,

```
<param name="file" value="demoApplication.log" />
```

searches for the file in the following location:

```
System.out.println( System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + 
                    "demoApplication.log" );
```

You could also use absolute paths. Additionally, verify that you have write permissions on the destination folder.

Comment: It's under windows all should work with default permission. What does `user.dir` exactly mean? I went out it for simplify, but much better put loggers into `logs` folder.

Comment: With `System.getProperty("user.dir")` you get the working directory for Java. See [System Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).